# focusout event on alt keypress does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, alt

I am using [jQuery Token Input](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) plugin with one of my custom written plugins in one of my projects.

My plugin basically adds an anchor tag to an element that it was initialized on and upon clicking the anchor link a text input element is shown which is bound to `jquery token input` plugin.

On `FocusOut` event i want to hide the text input (in this case which would be a `ul` initialized by jquery token input in place of the text input).

All works fine till now.

But if I press the alt key, the main `ul` is hidden as expected but the dropdown `ul` is still visible.

To see the problem that i am facing you can also view this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dHSWu/). Sorry, about the CSS part, i did include the CSS file but for some reason it does not work as expected.

Now, in the fiddle if you click the `+ Add` button the input and the dropdown (with instructions) appears, then if you click anywhere else in the preview window, it disappears, which is what is expected behaviour.

But if you click on the add button and once the input and dropdown appears and then if you press the alt key (which initiates the focusout event) the input disappears but the dropdown still shows. Why is that ?

What could be the reason causing this ?

#### Update:

I apologize if I made it a little complicated. Following is comparison between the expected behavior and the problem.

#### Case 1: (focusout event triggered by clicking somewhere in the body).

In this case, A user clicks on the +Add button > An input box appears with an open dropdown > A user focuses out by clicking somewhere else in the body > The Input and dropdown disappears.

This is the expected behaviour.

#### Case 2: (focusout event triggered on `alt` keypress).

In this case, A user clicks on the +Add button > An input box appears with an open dropdown > A user presses the `alt` key which triggers the focusout event > The Input disappears but dropdown does not.

I need to make sure the dropdown disappears in this case too.

Note: The Dropdown CSS is messed up in the fiddle for some reason. The text that says `type somethig` is the dropdown element.

Comment: nothing is happening when i press alter key after clicking on add button.

Comment: what do you mean nothing is happening ?

Comment: do you still see the text `type something ..` after pressing alt ? That should disappear once you hit alt.

Comment: When i click on add link, a text box and 'type something' is shown but i press alt key then the text box does not disappear

Comment: Please, explain your issue briefly . As i understand , it is a pb of keypress event .

Comment: What's the tag(by tagname, by id,by className) which includes ('type something' ) text?

Comment: thats `ul.token-input-dropdown` which is added by the jquery token input plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Add shortcut library and add the following code . It works

```
shortcut.add("Alt", function() {
   $('.token-input-dropdown').hide()
        });
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/dHSWu/5/

Likewise,be kept away the tags using `margin` to avoid overlapping  of events

```
a.addInput{
    margin:2px;
}
div.token-input-dropdown{
     margin:2px;
}
```

Comment: It still does not work for me. I pressed Add -> Textbox and dropdown appeared -> press alt -> disaappeared -> press alt -> the dropdown comes back again ??

Comment: could it be related to the operating system, i am on Ubuntu 12.04